# How to resume count down timer after closing dialogue/alert box

Tags: java, android, timer

I am creating a quiz app.I have a running count down timer on Quiz activity. I want to show a dialogue /alert box in between. When the dialogue box is open the count down timer is stopped. But when dialogue box is closed count down timer fails to start again. please help.

here is my code

```
btnHint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 timer.cancel();// working fine
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Read Carefully");
                dialog.setMessage(c.getString(7));
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit Hint", null);
                dialog.show();
                //how to start TIMER again after clicking 'Exit Hint'

                    }


                            });
```

I have already a countdown timer defined in onCreate as follows

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String time = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                tvClock.setText("Time" + "\n" + time + "/90");
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                if (seconds >= 31) {
                    tvClock.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boxgreen);
                } else if (seconds >= 16) {
                    tvClock.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boxyellow);
                } else {
                    tvClock.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boxred);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to save CountDownTimer's milis into a variable because `timer.cancel();`     resets the timer. Then you create onClickListener for negative button in which you recreate the timer using saved milis.

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 10) {   //timer will count down 10 seconds and save time every 10ms
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        milis = millisUntilFinished;
                        //save time into field milis 
                        //Update your view with progress here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                };
                timer.start();
                btnHint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        timer.cancel();// working fine
                        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this);
                        dialog.setTitle("Read Carefully");
                        dialog.setMessage(c.getString(7));
                        dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit Hint", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                timer = new CountDownTimer(milis, 10) {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                         milis = millisUntilFinished;  
                                         //save time again if you want to pause it again
                        //Update your view with progress here
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinish() {

                                    }
                                };
                                timer.start();
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.show();
                    }


                });
```

Comment: Thank you @ Gregor Rant for a first reply on stack overflow.I am trying to implement it. Please show more enlightenment.

Comment: Edited my answer (forgot to change second timer to countdown to saved milis). Also make sure milis is your class field (if it's just a variable it won't compile). Please let me know if you have any further problems with implementation!

Comment: In your implementation all you have to do is save millisUntilFinished and when you want to resume timer (in dialog onclick) you recreate the same timer but with the saved duration

Comment: Thanks @ Gregor Rant. It is working fine after a little modification.Thank you very much.